# Google drive preview "/image" API doesn't work anymore?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

Few days ago I was able to make request to:
https://drive.google.com/a/{{domain}}/file/d/{{docDriveId}}/image?pagenumber=1&w=400

Via this API I was able to get image preview on multi-page documents.

Seems it's there, but times-out after some time. It doesn't work anymore. Does anyone know what happened? It seems there's no documentation on this API.

On the other hand, I am aware of the thumbnailLink URL when getting document object via API, but this will only get 1st page preview.

Any alternative solutions to this?

Thanks a lot,
M

Answer (score 0):

That URL is not a part of the official Drive API and is not guaranteed to remain stable. The Drive API doesn't include the ability to fetch per-page image previews of documents, but you may want to investigate using the `embedLink` as an alternative: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files